# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError when using apache poi library?

Tags: java, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror

`I am trying to read a excel file. I am not sure what I am missing here. But I am getting error attached below. My variable book also shows that this variable is never used even though it is used in very next line. I assume it is related somehow but not sure how. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Error: Unable to initialize main class myExcelProject.MyExcelFileReader
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
`

```
package myExcelProject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class MyExcelFileReader {
    private String[][] inputs;
    private static String[][] excelInputs;
    private static Row row;
    private static Cell cell;   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
                excelInputs=readExcelTable("Excel Report.xlsx");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       

    }

    public static String[][] readExcelTable(String excelFile) throws IOException{

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFile));
        Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
        int lastRowNum = firstSheet.getLastRowNum();

        String[][] excelReadout = new String[lastRowNum][4];
        for (int i = 3; i < lastRowNum; i++) {
            row = firstSheet.getRow(i);
            if (row == null) {
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    cell = row.getCell(j, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                    if (cell == null) {
                        // do nothing
                    } else {
                        excelReadout[i][j]=cell.toString();
                        //System.out.print(cell.toString());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        return excelReadout;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

moved jar from Modulepath to Classpaths section in eclipse. Solved the issue.